# How to remove the border line below TButton on Windows XP?

Tags: image, delphi, button, windows-xp, rendering

I have a standard button placed on the nonuniform background (TImage). When the form was rendered by Windows XP, I started to see the border below my button:

[image: TButton render on Windows XP]

Can I fix this artefact somehow?

The same button looks normally on Windows 7:

[image: TButton render on Windows 7]

I have Delphi 2010, Windows XP SP3

Comment: It looks like a "standard" shadow for a button. You could try setting the button to be flat?

Comment: @Marjan Venema: Yes, flat button do not have this border line. But this button must be the standard "push-button". Customer wants the artefact to be removed

Comment: Why is your customer need such a feature ,i feel it is pointless even if you can get an answer ,still the button looks like xp button ,If you want nice windows 7 like buttons use some third party controls

Comment: @vibeeshanRC: if you know such third party controls, please tell me.

Comment: There seems to be a 1px-wide area of a different background shade just to the right of the "problematic" button too, which, however, is not as prominent as the line beneath the button. I wonder if the two lines are included in the button's dimensions. I am not very experienced in customised drawing of components so I can't provide you with a real pointer, but basically I would start searching for a way of spoofing the component into thinking it is drawing on a wider area than it is actually, something about handling the WM_NCPAINT message, perhaps.

Comment: In any event, you'd still have to check if the environment is the specific one you must account for, i.e. the right version of Windows and/or the right (or, rather, ‘wrong’) theme.

Comment: Actually, have you tried putting the button on a transparent TPanel with the dimensions that just allow you to hide the offending line?

Comment: @Andriy M: Yes! The panel can be the solution. Please add this as answer, probably I'll select it if this will be enough for my customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place the button on a `TPanel` and set the panel's dimensions just so it would hide the ‘artefact’. The panel's `ParentBackground` property should be set to `True` (and it is so by default).

I'm not sure if the artefact line is within the button's dimensions as specified in its properties, so may be you would have to add a check to your application to see whether it is being run under Windows XP, to adjust the panel's height appropriately.